# Why is my change to a range-for loop not work?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, foreach

I'm at a loss. I am trying to sum two numbers of vector such that they equal target, then return their indices; however, when running the code with a C++11 for-loop, the result is incorrect. With vector [2,7,11,15] and target=9, the result for the C++11 loop is [0, 0]. Using the C-style loop, it is [0,1]. What gives?

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSumCstyle(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<int> sol(2);
        bool found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i< nums.size()-1; i++ ){
            for ( int x = i +1; x <nums.size(); x++){
                if (nums[i] + nums[x] == target) {
                    sol[0] = i;
                    sol[1] = x;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) break; 
        }
        return sol;  
    }

    vector<int> twoSumC11(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<int> sol(2);
        bool found = false;
        for (int i : nums ){
            for ( int x = i +1; x <nums.size(); x++){
                if (nums[i] + nums[x] == target) {
                    sol[0] = i;
                    sol[1] = x;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) break; 
        }
        return sol;  
    } 
};
```

Comment: Because in `for (int i : nums)`, `i` will contain values from `nums`, not indices.

Comment: Do you expect `for (int i = 0; i< nums.size()-1; i++ )` and `for (int i : nums )` to be equivalent? The former iterates indices while the latter iterates the entries of `nums`.

Comment: Also note that `for (int i = 0; i< nums.size()-1; i++ )` skips the last entry in `nums`, whereas `for (int i : nums )` includes the last entry. You can't skip entries in a range-for loop without using a more restrictive range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer loop is setting `i` to the actual value within your `nums` vector, but your inner loop is using it as if it's an index! As an explicit example, on the first iteration of your outer loop, `i` will be `2` and so your inner loop will start at `x : 3`.

Since you're actually interested in the index as part of your calculations, it probably just makes the most sense to use the traditional-style for-loop.